# Record trigger flow in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

We can't save this record because the “pp” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. insufficient access rights on cross-reference id Error ID:

I am getting these error when i am deploying record trigger flow in salesforce org and trying to insert record in the required object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does the flow set a record type on this object? If it does - does your profile / permission sets grant you access to that record type?

Does the flow use some data coming from managed package and you don't have a license (or again - Profile rights to at least see the referenced object)

Answer (score -1):

Examine all the objects related to the core object you're saving to. Chances are that even if the user has rights to the core object, there's a relationship in there somewhere where the user doesn't have access.

For example, say the flow is trying to save a record to Object A, which is a detail record on Account (account is the master). The user, through permissions (profile or permission set) has at least Create rights on Object A, and at least Read and Edit rights on Account. However, due to the user's role and sharing rules, they only have Read access to the Account. The user will be prevented from saving the record in Object A, and the "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" will be thrown.

Comment: its all english this isn't a clear answer.

Comment: I can only remove my downvote if you update your answer. Please kindly fix your answer though this platform is meant for developers to provide insightful and useful suggestions/solutions.